# i don't know how to add the user input back to the DOM and i think its something with my js code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I don't konw what to do

I need help with this js script and I just need to know how to show a user  input in a html styled templet that I made but I just don't don't known how

```html
<!-- add email side nav -->
<div id="side-form" class="sidenav side-form">
  <form class="add-email container section">
    <h6>add a new email</h6>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="input-field">
      <input keypath="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" id="title" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="title">write email here</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>Notifications</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-field center">
      <button class="btn-floating blue pulse" id="add_email" onclick="getValue()">Add</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What js script ? You only provided HTML...

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your JS file or `<script>` tag:

```
const userInput = document.getElementById("title")

userInput.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    // append e.target.value to the page
    document.createElement("p").innerText = e.target.value;
});
```

The above will append a paragraph to your page with the value of the email in it. It is now part of the Dom. Obviously, you will change the logic inside the event listener to render it to your page appropriately. Alternatively, you can set an event listener to the add-button and render it from there.